# How do I reference a pointer from a different class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, view, controllers

First off, I despise singletons with a passion. Though I should probably be trying to use one, I just don't want to. I want to create a data class (that is instantiated only once by a view controller on loading), and then using a different class, message the crap out of that data instance until it is brimming with so much data, it smiles.

So, how do I do that? I made a pointer to the instance of the data class when I instantiated it. I'm now over in a separate view controller, action occurs, and I want to update the initial data object. I think I need to reference that object by way of pointer, but I have no idea how to do that. Yes, I've set properties and getters and setters, which seem to work, but only in the initial view controller class.

Comment: So you want a class, thats instantiated once, purely to store data. You might hate them but thats a text book def of a singleton as far as I'm aware.

Comment: What is the problem with the singletons?..
Could you show your code, please?

Comment: @Rudiger: So, whats the problem with simply creating one instance of it then? Jalfs nice post on the subject: [Singletons: Solving problems you didn’t know you never had since 1995](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/).

Comment: I don't understand your question sorry. If Justagruvn wants a class to store data and have another class retrieve the data out of it I would assume there would be multiple classes wanting data out of it otherwise he would just use ivars. I like singletons for the right purpose

Comment: Maybe I'm reading too much into the question. If you are simply wanting to access an ivar from an instance that is loaded from where your ivar is stored then don't use a singleton. But the way I read your question you should use a singleton. If its the first way i think using super.ivarname should get you access to the var...maybe

Comment: Just read that article, although he has a slight point all the examples he has I would never use a singleton for. And to say that you should never use singletons because later on you might want two of them is pretty stupid. Use singletons for the right purpose. Probably the reason I jumped to using a singleton was because the author thought he should use a singleton but hated them. IMO if you hate something but know you should use it but want to find a way around not using it - just use it.

Comment: @Rudiger: Its only the OP who thinks singletons are suited here - ignore the first sentences and i don't see a reason for them here. *"Pretty stupid"* is adding context to a text that wasn't there before, it doesn't say to *never* use singletons. And as for using them for this problem, is the question anywhere saying that there *logically can't be more than one instance* of the class?

Comment: If there is more than one instance of the class the data in the class will not be maintained

Comment: " I'm now over in a separate view controller" says to me that the requesting class isn't related to the class that set the data. So you can do it 4 ways, global (shouldn't use), singleton, database and file system. Writing to the file system or a database is probably overkill by the sounds of his example. In the bottom of the  bloggers example he says if you do need to use globals you should either use globals, static class members(isn't that the same thing as he doesn't like, compile time enforcing that there is only one instance) Also iPhone sdk makes thread safe access easier.

Comment: A singleton is effectively an overly complicated global unless there logically can't be more than one instance. With more details of the applications design i'm quite certain that there is a better way than using globals, disguised or not.

Comment: You guys are awesome! Thank you all for your time in answering my question. I really do appreciate it. 

Hating singletons was out of line. and for that Mr. Singleton, I am sorry. That being said. We make view controllers all the time that only get instantiated once, and everyone things thats ok. I just wanted to make a data class object that I could talk to. You are right. FirstLevelviewcontroller instantiates second level view controller and data object. I just want to know how to get second level view controller to talk to the data object. Thanks again guys/gals.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use a singleton if you don't like the pattern or if it doesn't fit. Assuming you are creating your second view controller in the first one, just declare an ivar and property for your model object in your second view controller and when you instantiate it, assign the model object to this property.

Comment: Thats true but if if hes not creating the second view in the first one then he will run into trouble. When the author said "I'm now over in a separate view controller" I assumed the two were unrelated. I guess its hard to give an exact answer without more imformation.

Answer (score 0):

Make a global variable for your object and store it there on creation. You can wire that up in the init method (probably bad style), or from the caller or via interface builder. Just make your variable known in the files that use it.

Or - well - use some kind of singleton pattern and get the instance directly from that class. Looks much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Seriously use a singleton. In case you don't like them cause you don't know the code:

```
@interface Order : NSObject {
NSMutableArray *order;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *order;

+ (Order *)sharedInstance;

@end

#import "Order.h"


@implementation Order

@synthesize order;

+(Order *)sharedInstance {
static Order *myInstance = nil;

@synchronized(self) {
    if(!myInstance) {
        myInstance = [[Order alloc] init];
        }
    }
return myInstance;
}

-(void)dealloc {
    [order release];
    [super dealloc];

}
@end
```

Comment: What if we don't like them because they're bad? What if we don't like them because we prefer to avoid globals? What if we don't like them because they're hard to make thread-safe? What if we don't like them because they're unnecessary? What if we don't like them because they needlessly constrain our code and prevent reuse?

Comment: Sometimes you just need globals its rare but it happens, if you find it hard to make them thread safe in the iPhone SDK because it does it all for you you're doing it wrong, just like globals sometimes you just need them. You are making a sweeping statement. Just like people say you should never use tables in HTML, if you want to display a table, use a table. Don't get into the elitist stuff. Although I jumped to conclusions about what the author was doing all I was doing was posting a singleton code because when I first needed a global it was hard to code and not thread safe singlton fixed it

Comment: My reason was I made a tab bar app, I had one variable that was used across all tabs, it was started in the app delegate. I could use a global which was harder to access, I could write it to a file (slow on iPhone and unnecessary as next time the App was opened I didn't need it) or a database (overkill) so whats left?

Answer (score 0):

Um. Hello. Isn't Core Data a good enough framework for you? It allows you to have a single persistent store and multiple contexts to manage updates and merging of changes in response to notifications. I may be out of line here, but seeing how you start the question with a strong opinion about a well accepted pattern in your first question indicates that you have not spent much time discovering the ways in which the objective c runtime and Foundation classes in iOS can collaborate to achieve a task. In any software, one object *and only one* object owns a specific resource. You should embrace singletons. I suggest you spend some time reading  http://www.cocoadesignpatterns.com/. Oh yeah, check out the meaning of KVO.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make it a property of your app delegate? That way *you* don't have to use the singleton pattern but you are taking advantage of Apple's already existing usage of the singleton pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget that Objective-C is a superset of C.

Basically, a data class is a plain C `struct`.

If you want to access a variable of that class from another class, make it global.

mydata.h:

```
struct MyData {
    // Whatever data fields that you need, e.g.:
    NSInteger value;
};

extern struct MyData mydata;
```

mydata.c:

```
struct MyData mydata = {
    // Whatever initial value that you find relevant, e.g.:
    .value = 42;
};
```